# How to get product Id from hidden field Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the `Id` of a product when I submit the form using the hidden input field but am getting an error `Trying to get property of non-object` . How can I fix this issue?

code

Controller

```
class productController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $userId = $request->user()->id;
    $products = product::where('admin', $userId)->get();
   return view('admin.product.index',compact('products'));
}



/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function admin()
{
   $products=product::all();
   return view('admin.product.index',compact('products'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request) 
{ 

    $formInput=$request->all();
    $image=array();
    if($files=$request->file('image')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('images',$name);
            $image[]=$name;

        }
       // dd($formInput);

    }

    //dd($formInput); 
    Image::create(array_merge($formInput,[
       // $id=$request->input('id'), 
       // $product=Product::find($id),
        $request->input('product_id'),
    ])); 
    return redirect()->back(); 

}
```

blade

```
   <form action="{{route('product.store')}}" method="post" 
   role="form" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{csrf_field()}}
  @foreach ( $products as $product )
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $product->id 
   }}" />
    @endforeach
    </form>
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Your controller syntax looks weird to me. Can you make it more readable?

Comment: I hope now is more readable @vivek_23

Comment: Why do you initialize in one `$product=Product::find($id)` and access in another array location `'product_id' =>$product->id`? Could you first get the product and then do the array_merge?

Comment: how do I do that? @vivek_23

Comment: Ok, I would let you know but before that can you tell me why  value of the `id` in `value=""` is empty?

Comment: The value is empty because I tried `@foreach ( $products as $product )` and `<input type="hidden" value={{ $product->product_id }} />` and I always get an error products is undefined @vivek_23

Comment: Ok, you would have to share the entire blade file first. Also, `{{ $product->product_id }}` should most likely be `{{ $product->id }}`.

Comment: Please check the updated blade @vivek_23

Comment: Ok, looks fine to me from what you shared and you shouldn't be getting `undefined variable products` in your blade? Does your blade extend any parent blade where `$products` is required?

Comment: It extends master blade which has nothing to do with product@vivek_23

Comment: This is hard to debug. Is there a way you could share this so that I could reproduce it on my end?

Comment: Can we move to discussion chat ?@vivek_23

Comment: Sorry, I would like to help here itself.

Comment: what code do you need so that you can fix the problem? @vivek_23

Comment: Probably share a git repo. Also, can you let me know when does this happen? When you load the form or after you submit the form? Can you share a snapshot?

Comment: You can check the error here https://imgur.com/rTmU1MP @vivek_23

Comment: This shows the line but I want to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have more than 1 `product_id` hidden field.

If you plan to submit more than 1 add square brackets to then name `product_id[]`.

Request object should retrieve the same name. You are using `id` in controller, but submitting `product_id` named field.

Use `$request->input('product_id')`

Comment: the problem is it keeps showing `Undefined variable: products` in blade @Pseudo

Comment: You need to pass the `$products` variable to the view. Are you doing that in the controller? Something like `return view('viewname')->with('products', $products);`

Comment: yeah I have this `return view('admin.product.index',compact('products'));` @Pseudo

Comment: How are you setting `$products` variable? You are not setting it in the example code you put under controller.

Comment: Like this `$products = product::where('admin')->get();` @Pseudo

Comment: Want to include a complete example for controller code?